# Converting string representation of an array back to array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json

I have a string representation of an array as below

```
 "[name = preload cacheHits = 30 onDiskHits = 4 inMemoryHits = 26 misses = 0 size = 2913 averageGetTime = 0.1 evictionCount = 0 ]\n[  name = information cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0 ]"
```

I am trying to convert it back to an array , I tried with Javascript but is there a way we can do it java?

```
 let string = "[name = preload cacheHits = 30 onDiskHits = 4 inMemoryHits = 26 misses = 0 size = 2913 averageGetTime = 0.1 evictionCount = 0 ]\n[  name = information cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0 ]"
 let arr = string.split('\n');
 arr.forEach((element) => {
          this.orginalArray = JSON.parse(element);
        });
```

but it's giving me an error

```
 Unexpected token a in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (m.vue?90cd:84)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (M.vue?90cd:83)
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: The string (even after splitting) is not valid JSON and cannot be parsed this way!

Comment: What is the expected output for this input? An array of associative arrays or an array of objects? If you have control over the creation of the string, it's better to fix that to create a valid JSON string.

Comment: How can this be parsed then, any advice?

Comment: @adiga I don't have the control over the creation of this string. and both expected output like an array of associative arrays or an array of objects would work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of transforming that string into an array of objects:

```js
let string = "[name = preload cacheHits = 30 onDiskHits = 4 inMemoryHits = 26 misses = 0 size = 2913 averageGetTime = 0.1 evictionCount = 0 ]\n[  name = information cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0 ]"

console.log(
  string
    // split items by newline
    .split('\n')
    // map each item to an object
    .map(item => Object.fromEntries(
      // word characters followed by equal sign followed by word characters
      item.match(/\w+\s*=\s*\w+/g)
        // split by equal sign and trim each part
        .map(entry => entry.split('=').map(part => part.trim()))
    ))
);
```

Reference:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)
- [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and the [browser compatibility table](https://caniuse.com/#search=fromEntries) since this is relatively new